# How to remove OUTPUTS in PHP without papge breaking

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to remove some outputs in a php module but everytime I do so the page goes blank when i try to view it in a browser. Tried it for a couple of hours without luck. Perhaps someone here can help me.

```
<?php
if (!defined('_INDEX_CALLED')) {
die();
}
/* Admin home */

$output .= '    <div class="dashboard">
 <ul class="dashhead"><li><a href="#" class="active" id="tsel">WU Donations</a></li></ul>
';

$output .= '<br><br><table class="tblhover">
<tr style="font-weight: 700"><td>ID</td><td>Sender</td><td>Account</td><td>Amount</td><td>MTCN</td><td>Sent</td></tr>
';

$sql = 'select * from cp_westernunion order by submittime desc';
$donres = sqlsrv_query($gamecp_conn, $sql);
while ($donrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($donres)) {
$output .= '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$donrow['id'].'">'.$donrow['id'].'</td><td>'.$donrow['sname'].'</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="accountserial" value="'.$donrow['saccount'].'"><a href="/accountinfo?accountid='.$donrow['saccount'].'">'.$donrow['saccount'].'</a></td>
<td>'.$donrow['samount'].'</td><td>'.$donrow['mtcn'].'</td><td>'.$donrow['submittime'].'</td>
<td><select name="status">';
foreach ($status as $s) {
    $selected = $s == $donrow['rcvstatus'] ? ' selected' : '';
    $output .= '<option value="'.$s.'"'.$selected.'>'.$s.'</option>
';
}
$gp = $donrow['gp'] != null ? $donrow['gp'] : 0;
$pd = $donrow['processtime'] != null ? $donrow['processtime'] : '';
$aa = $donrow['actualamount'] != null ? $donrow['actualamount'] : 0;
$output .= '</select></td><td>'.$pd.'</td>
<td><input type="text" name="actual" value="'.$aa.'" style="width: 50px"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="addgp" value="'.$gp.'" style="width: 50px"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Apply" class="wusubmit"></td></tr>
';
}

$output .= '      </table>
</div>
';

$documenttitle = 'Admin &ndash; Western Union';

$additionalheaders='';

$documentloaded = '$(".wusubmit").click(function() {
 var id = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name=id]").val();
  var mtcn = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name=mtcn]").val();
  var status = $(this).parents("tr").find("select[name=status]").val();
  var actual = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name=actual]").val();
  var gpadd = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name=addgp]").val();
  var accountserial = $(this).parents("tr").find("input[name=accountserial]").val();
  var that = $(this);
$.post("/includes/ajax/processwu.php", {
id: id,
mtcn: mtcn,
status: status,
actual: actual,
gpadd: gpadd,
accountserial: accountserial
}).done(function(data) {
if (data == "success.") {
  $(that).css("background", "#6aa370");
  $(that).prop("disabled", true);
}
else {
  window.alert(data);
  $(that).text("OOOPS...");
}
});
return false;
});';

?>
```

The part where I am trying to remove outputs is this part:

```
while ($donrow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($donres)) {
$output .= '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$donrow['id'].'">'.$donrow['id'].'</td><td>'.$donrow['sname'].'</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="accountserial" value="'.$donrow['saccount'].'"><a href="/accountinfo?accountid='.$donrow['saccount'].'">'.$donrow['saccount'].'</a></td>
<td>'.$donrow['samount'].'</td><td>'.$donrow['mtcn'].'</td><td>'.$donrow['submittime'].'</td>

//Remove from here
<td><select name="status">';
foreach ($status as $s) {
    $selected = $s == $donrow['rcvstatus'] ? ' selected' : '';
    $output .= '<option value="'.$s.'"'.$selected.'>'.$s.'</option>
';
}
$gp = $donrow['gp'] != null ? $donrow['gp'] : 0;
$pd = $donrow['processtime'] != null ? $donrow['processtime'] : '';
$aa = $donrow['actualamount'] != null ? $donrow['actualamount'] : 0;
$output .= '</select></td><td>'.$pd.'</td>
<td><input type="text" name="actual" value="'.$aa.'" style="width: 50px"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="addgp" value="'.$gp.'" style="width: 50px"></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Apply" class="wusubmit"></td></tr>
';
//To here
}
```

When I do it, it just gives me a blank page when loading the page, so not sure what there error is here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you remove `<td><select name="status">';` then you have removed the closing `';` from the previous line of code and you will need to add them back i.e. `$output .= '<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$donrow['id'].'">'.$donrow['id'].'</td><td>'.$donrow['sname'].'</td>
<td><input type="hidden" name="accountserial" value="'.$donrow['saccount'].'"><a href="/accountinfo?accountid='.$donrow['saccount'].'">'.$donrow['saccount'].'</a></td>
<td>'.$donrow['samount'].'</td><td>'.$donrow['mtcn'].'</td><td>'.$donrow['submittime'].'</td>';`

Comment: Also, you would want to keep the closing `</tr>`.

Comment: Awesome, can you add that as reply so I can accept it ;-)